# What 3d framework for flash should i use?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d

Which one os the best? Seems, like papervision is no longer updated and away3d is only for flash player 11. And I need a good (maintained) free framework to start with with flash player 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Away3D is not only for flash player 11... there are already several instances of Away3D for as3, though the team has moved on to flash 11 3d stuff and how much maintenance there is for the fp10 version of Away3D I do not know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends if you are aiming at the current tech (CPU rendering) or the next-gen Stage3D APIs (GPU rendering). FP11 has gone into beta, and it probably won't be too long before its released into the wild - it opens up a lot of doors that prior versions simply couldn't. Whatever you do with the current gen stuff, keep your eyes on Stage3d. It's a game-changer.

At any rate - which one is the best? The one you know, or the one that makes the most sense to you. If you are just getting into flash 3d, then it can't hurt to test several out.

**GPU rendering (>= FP11)**
 
Away3d(broomstick) - is probably the right choice, given its community of users and documentation (it's not just FP11, btw, its been around for several years). It has a great feature set and is pretty easy to get up and running. You can not go wrong.

Alternativa3d - I don't have much experience with it (my understanding was that it wasn't a pure actionscript solution - that may change with Stage3D), but the results are quite good.

Unity3d - apparently is going to be integrating SWF / AS3 support. It is a robust middleware platform, and it's awesomeness cannot be overstated. It will support scripting in AS3 and export SWFs. How cool is that?

**CPU rendering (<= FP10)**
Papervision3D - although it is no longer being supported (or actively improved, anyway), I feel that it remains a quality solution. PV2.0 has a lot of really nice features, and straightforward to use. Considering *all work* on non-Stage3D frameworks are likely to *slow the hell down*, PV2.0 is as good as any other choice (and arguably better).

Away3D is also quite good. It was a fork of Papervision, so if you have any experience with that, Away will be very familiar. The real bonus with Away3d is that when FP11 does release, you will be able to integrate with the new features pretty seamlessly, as the architecture of the central framework hasn't changed that much.

There are several others (Sandy3d, Five3d, Alternativa etc. ) but I have no experience with them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx, seems like away3d is a great choice :)

Comment: I've spent a lot of time with papervision3d (I'm currently finishing up a PV project, actually, and still really like it). But at this point - Away3d is definitely the right choice. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

[Alternativa3D](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/alternativa3d/) seems to be the winner these days.

Answer (score 0):

Away3D is not just for Flash Player 11. The latest stable release can be found here :  http://away3d.com/download/away3d_3.6.0